# Tick Reporter For Breed Color Transformation

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a reporter for when the first transformation of one ant breed from one color to another color (violet) occurs, but I have no idea what code to use. My attempt (in a monitor) brings up the END expected error, which is incorrect, but it is probably just signalling some other code error.

```
to-report group-recruitment-initiation
let potential-recruiter followers with [color = violet]
if any? potential-recruiter
  report ticks
end
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Without testing it, I can see two problems.  First `report ticks` should have brackets around it.  Second, if the `if` condition is false, then the reporter will hit the `end` statement without reporting anything, which NetLogo will see as an error.  Reporting `-1` in such a case would make NetLogo happy, but you'll need to think about what that will mean for your monitor.